# Drupal multi-page webform have multiple submits

Tags: drupal

I have a problem with my multi-page webform, I need to have a form alter and an extra submit on this form but the problem is that the form alter is called on each page, and the form submit too, so my custom code is called on each page.

For the alter I just make a hook_form_alter like this :

```
function ga_voyage_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state , $form_id){
  dsm($form_id);
  if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_701'){
     .....
    $form['#submit'][] = 'ga_voyage_extra_submit';
  }
}
```

And my extra submit :

```
function ga_voyage_extra_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  ...
}
```

how can I have one alter called at the beginning and one submit called at the end ? And no on each page

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Store value of current step into form_state and add condition into alter on it

Comment: I try to add `$form_state['page'] = 0;` in the alter and increment in the submit but the form throw me an alter on each page of the form, I think it will work if I create the field with the webform in hidden

Comment: It seems work but have a strange behavior, on the first page my alter and submit code is executed one time, for the second page two time, and for the third page two times too

Comment: use static value

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7.x